# Get only user OU from Active Directory Using Powershell/CLI

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get only `OU` of specific user.

Example the command should display what `OU` user `JOHN`  belongs to:

```
USERNAME = OU_NAME
```

Comment: ok got it
`
$user = get-aduser ims
$uo = $user.distinguishedname.substring($user.distinguishedname.indexof(",") + 1,$user.distinguishedname.Length - $user.distinguishedname.indexof(",") - 1)
write-host "$($user.Name) = $uo"
`

Comment: String parsing does not work in many AD implementations that use the `,` character in names.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the AD-Module installed, you can also use this. I found this very useful when I ran scripts where I needed AD-Information, but didn't have the AD-Module installed. :

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$env:username))"
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
$objUser = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
$DN = $objUser.distinguishedName
$ADVal = [ADSI]"LDAP://$DN"
$WorkOU = $ADVal.Parent
$WorkOU
```

Now `$WorkOU` would return a string like this `LDAP://OU=userou,OU=userou2,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com` which you can filter any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity [USERNAME] -Properties CanonicalName

$userOU = ($user.DistinguishedName -split ",",2)[1]
```

Source: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/discovering-a-users-ou/

Comment: The weird `split` syntax is documented in [about_split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7#max-substrings) and means "split on the first comma (into at most 2 substrings) and return the second (`[1]`) part as the OU.

Answer (score 1):

The [Get-ADPathname.ps1 script](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-active-directory-paths) provides one very simple technique for this that doesn't require string parsing:

```
PS C:\> (Get-ADUser kendyer).DistinguishedName | Get-ADPathname -Format X500Parent
OU=Sales,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

(String parsing is not robust, as stated in the article.)

Comment: The link is dead, and the web archive says it moved to https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/use-powershell-handle-active-directory-paths

Comment: Moved to a module: https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-ADName

Answer (score 0):

I used the script from Laage, but changed it slightly because we use ',' in our names. After the change it will stil work for names without ','.

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity [USERNAME]

$userOU = ($user.DistinguishedName -split "=",3)[-1]

Answer (score -2):

Some time the name includes a comma. The best solution I have found is this one:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity [USERNAME] -Properties CanonicalName
$userOU = "OU="+($user.DistinguishedName -split ",OU=",2)[1]
```

Comment: This just copies Laage's answer from 2017.